# Renderizar HTML en blade de Laravel

Tags: php, bootstrap, laravel, laravel-4

Tengo el siguiente problema, quiero renderizar html dentro de un template hecho con balde de laravel.

lo tengo de la siguiente forma:

```
 <i class="n-icon-help-circled" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-placement="right" title="{{ '<p>' . _('Hola') . '</p><p>' . _('Mundo.') . '</p>' }}"></i>
```

En la cual `_('Hola')` y el `_('Mundo.')` son métodos que están en una clase interna para la globalización.

El problema es que no logro hacer que me rnederize el HTML, lo que hace es mostrar el texto:

```
'<p>Hola</p><p>Mundo</p>'
```

Y lo que necesito es que muestre el Hola mundo sin los tags.

He intentado hacerlo con esto `{!! !!}` y con este `{!!html_entity_decode( '<p>' . _('Hola') . '</p><p>' . _('Mundo.') . '</p>')!!}` y no logro hacer que me muestre el texto como quiero.

Disculpen pero no se mucho de Laravel. La versión del Framework es 4.2

P.D: Si uso un  echo lo muestra de manera correcta. Si quito los tags html y trato de hacer un retorno `\n` me da un error de caracter no permitido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final confundí 2 cosas importantes acá, y era el uso de Laravel con Bootstrap. Esto no es un problema como tal de Laravel solo necesitaba colocarle `data-html="true"` al `<i>`, adicionalemnte dejar los tags HTML fuera de las `{{}}` del template (Me dicen que es una buena practica) y listo, Al final quedaría así:

```
<i class="n-icon-help-circled" data-html="true" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-placement="right" title="<p>{{_('Hola')}}</p><p>{{_('Mundo.')}}</p> }}"></i>
```